# Accessing Multiple Models with One Action

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I have multiple models within my index route which I declared like so:

```
App.IndexRoute = Em.Route.extend({
  model: function(){   
   return Ember.RSVP.hash({
     dogs: this.store.find('dog'),
     cats: this.store.find('cat')
  })
})
```

And I'm able to render them fine by doing this:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
  {{render 'dogs' dogs}}
  {{render 'cats' cats}}
</script>
```

The problem I am facing now, is that I want to pass a single action from the index to specific actions on each of these models controllers.  I've tried this:

```
App.IndexController = Em.ObjectController.extend({
  needs: ['cats', 'dogs'],  
  actions: {   
    indexAction: function() {      
      this.get('controllers.cats').send('catAction')
      this.get('controllers.dogs').send('dogAction')
    }
  }
})
```

Which calls the appropriate functions but these function use the `this` keyword which is seems to be bound differently when called directly.

Does anyone have any suggestions?