# Accessing Ember Controller with Mixins

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

This question is related to [this question I asked earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21095364/accessing-multiple-models-with-one-action).  I have a Cat Model which has an associated CatsController.  I have added the EmberCrossfilter Mixin like so:

```
App.CatsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend(EmberCrossfilter, {
  // stuff here
});
```

I now want to call an action on this controller from my index controller and can do this like so:

```
App.IndexController = Em.ObjectController.extend({
  needs: ['cats', 'dogs'],  
  actions: {   
    indexAction: function() {      
      this.get('controllers.cats').send('catAction')
      this.get('controllers.dogs').send('dogAction')
    }
  }
})
```

The action gets called but if I look at the `this` object I get something that doesn't have the mixin properties and has an array length of 0:

```
__ember1389647609449: undefined
__ember1389647609449_meta: Meta
_childContainers: Object
_subControllers: Array[0]
_super: undefined
model: (...)
sortAscending: (...)
sortProperties: (...)
get sortProperties: function () {
set sortProperties: function (value) {
__proto__: Object
```

If I call the `catAction` method directly from my cats template, and look at the `this` object I see all the mixin properties and the array length is correct.

```
@each: (...)
get @each: function () {
set @each: function (value) {
__each: Class
__ember1389647609449: "ember425"
__ember1389647609449_meta: Meta
_childContainers: Object
_crossfilter: Object
_dimensionAge: Object
_dimensionColour: Object
_dimensionCountry: Object
_dimensionCuteness: Object
_dimensionDefault: Object
_dimensionName: Object
_dimensionNameRegexp: Object
_subControllers: Array[4]
_super: undefined
content: (...)
get content: function () {
set content: function (value) {
count: (...)
get count: function () {
set count: function (value) {
model: (...)
sortAscending: (...)
sortProperties: (...)
get sortProperties: function () {
set sortProperties: function (value) {
target: Class
toString: function () { return ret; }
__proto__: Object
```

This is causing me problems when trying to call the action from my index controller, because the passed CatsController doesn't have any of the mixin properties or methods.

Anyone have any ideas of how I can sort this out?

Comment: when you are saying you look at the `this` what's the context, are you in the `catAction`/`dogAction`

Comment: yes, inside the catAction.

Comment: This looks like it's working, can you show me what I've done different http://emberjs.jsbin.com/aSIZIbu/4/edit

Comment: You have been my savior lately @kingpin2k!! I'll have to wait till tomorrow to double check against my real version, but what you have worked perfectly.  I'm not sure what is different.  I updated it slightly to use Ember-Data, but it still works! http://jsbin.com/OSapEGAx/2/edit?html,js,console,output. Thank you so much, if you post answer I'll give you cred for sure!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mixin's properties may not appear right on the object itself, but if you call get on it the properties and getters/setters will be fetched

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/aSIZIbu/4/edit

Comment: This actually still isn't working.  I'm trying to recreate the problem in JSBin, but haven't had success.  I just keep adding parts, eventually I'll find it.  The problem is that EmberCrossfilter adds _dimension Properties on initialization that I can't access using get when called later on.  I changed the code to use set, but that still didn't work.  I'll let you know if I find it, but thought you might have some troubleshooting hints.

Comment: I think I recreated it, when pressing the index action everything is undefined  http://jsbin.com/IVaMUPO/2/edit