# Why is Ember Controller init called when controller is referenced from other controller?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

This question is related to [this earlier question I asked.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21101575/accessing-ember-controller-with-mixins) I thought I had the solution, but it appears to be more complex than I originally had thought.  I've successfully been able to implement Ember Crossfilter on a controller, but when I need to call an action on that controller from the index controller, for example, by doing something like this:

```
App.IndexController = Em.ObjectController.extend({
  needs: ['cats', 'dogs'],
  actions: {   
    indexAction: function() {      
      this.get('controllers.cats').send('catAction');
      this.get('controllers.dogs').send('dogAction');
    }
  }
});
```

It turns out that the corresponding cats and dogs controllers are completely rebuilt.  This probably usually isn't a big issue, but if those cats and dogs controllers are implementing something like crossfilter, having them rebuild on each action probably isn't very efficient.

I have a sufficient example of what I am talking about here:  http://jsbin.com/IVaMUPO/6/edit?js,console,output

You can see that on fresh load, that each controller is calling the `_createCrossfilter` methods and the `_createDimensions` methods.  These are kicked off in the `init` method.  Hitting the `dogAction` and `catAction` buttons do whats expected and everything is dandy.

The problem is that when clicking the `indexAction`, both the `dogAction` and `catAction` are kicked of, but this calls `init` again on both controllers.

Is this the correct behavior?  Is there a way around this?  Thanks for the help.